# Flutter margin при onFocus FocusNode

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-ui

Как установить отступ от края при попадании фокуса на определенную FocusNode?

Как видно из видео сверху от кнопок есть отступ но при прокрутке экрана и возвращении фокуса на кнопку, она прилипает к верху экрана, оно и понятно, кнопка на экране и в фокусе, а как сделать небольшой отсуп сверху?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class TestFocus extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 50,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          return Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => {},child:  Text("TEST"),),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: А где код? Или мы гадать должны?

Comment: А какой код вам нужен? Это обычные rawmaterial кнопки, логика смены фокусов под капотом флаттера.

Comment: Код вёрстки, проблема же явно не в кнопке, так?

Comment: из гифки не ясно? Окей, сейчас обновил вопрос с примером верстки, коль так удобнее

Comment: Ваш пример рабочий, в чем проблема?